# Load and duplicate 4 single precision float numbers into a packed __m256 variable with fewest instructions

Tags: c++, avx

I have a float array containing A,B,C,D 4 float numbers and I wish to load them into a `__m256` variable like AABBCCDD. What's the best way to do this?
I know using `_mm256_set_ps()` is always an option but it seems slow with 8 CPU instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have AVX2 available, for `vpmovzdq ymm, mem` (2 uops on Intel) to set up for `vmovsldup`?  Or simply AVX2 `vpermps` with a shuffle vector constant, after a 128-bit load.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes AVX2 is available. I'm targeting a common desktop CPU

Comment: Ok, then I'd recommend accepting my answer.  It's at least as good as Mike's answer on modern mainstream CPUs with AVX2.  (Or with clang, compiles to the same asm.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data was the result of another vector calculation (and in a __m128), you'd want AVX2 `vpermps` (`_mm256_permutexvar_ps`) with a control vector of `_mm256_set_epi32(3,3, 2,2,  1,1, 0,0)`.

`vpermps ymm` is 1 uop on Intel, but 2 uops on Zen2 (with 2 cycle throughput).  And 3 uops on Zen1 with one per 4 clock throughput.  (https://uops.info/)

If it was the result of separate scalar calculations, you might want to shuffle them together with `_mm_set_ps(d,d, c,c)` (1x vshufps) to set up for a vinsertf128.

---

But with data in memory, I think your best bet is **a 128-bit broadcast-load, then an in-lane shuffle**.  It only requires AVX1, and on modern CPUs it's 1 load + 1 shuffle uop on Zen2 and Haswell and later.  It's also efficient on Zen1: the only lane-crossing shuffle being the 128-bit broadcast-load.

Using an in-lane shuffle is lower-latency than lane-crossing on both Intel and Zen2 (256-bit shuffle execution units).  This still requires a 32-byte shuffle control vector constant, but if you need to do this frequently it will typically / hopefully stay hot in cache.

```
__m256  duplicate4floats(void *p) {
   __m256 v = _mm256_broadcast_ps((const __m128 *) p);   // vbroadcastf128
   v = _mm256_permutevar_ps(v, _mm256_set_epi32(3,3, 2,2,  1,1, 0,0));  // vpermilps
   return v;
}
```

**Modern CPUs handle broadcast-loads right in the load port**, no shuffle uop needed.  (Sandybridge does need a port 5 shuffle uop for `vbroadcastf128`, unlike narrower broadcasts, but Haswell and later are purely port 2/3.  But SnB doesn't support AVX2 so a lane-crossing shuffle with granularity less than 128-bit wasn't an option.)

So even if AVX2 is available, I think AVX1 instructions are more efficient here.  On Zen1, `vbroadcastf128` is 2 uops, vs. 1 for a 128-bit `vmovups`, but `vpermps` (lane-crossing) is 3 uops vs. 2 for `vpermilps`.

**Unfortunately, clang pessimizes this into a `vmovups` load and a `vpermps ymm`, but GCC compiles it as written.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dMzh3fezE))**

---

If you wanted to avoid using a shuffle-control vector constant, `vpmovzxdq ymm, [mem]` (2 uops on Intel) could get the elements set up for [`vmovsldup`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsldup) (1 uops in-lane shuffle).  Or broadcast-load and `vunpckl/hps` then blend?

---

> I know using _mm256_set_ps() is always an option but it seems slow with 8 CPU instructions.

Get a better compiler, then!  (Or remember to enable optimization.)

```
__m256  duplicate4floats_naive(const float *p) {
   return _mm256_set_ps(p[3],p[3], p[2], p[2], p[1],p[1], p[0],p[0]);
}
```

compiles with gcc (https://godbolt.org/z/dMzh3fezE) into

```
duplicate4floats_naive(float const*):
        vmovups xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        vpermilps       xmm0, xmm1, 80
        vpermilps       xmm1, xmm1, 250
        vinsertf128     ymm0, ymm0, xmm1, 0x1
        ret
```

So 3 shuffle uops, not great.  And it could have used `vshufps` instead of `vpermilps` to save code-size and let it run on more ports on Ice Lake.  But still vastly better than 8 instructions.

clang's shuffle optimizer makes the same asm as with my optimized intrinsics, because that's how clang is.  It's pretty decent optimization, just not quite optimal.

```
duplicate4floats_naive(float const*):
        vmovups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]
        vmovaps ymm1, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0] # ymm1 = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]
        vpermps ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        ret
```

Comment: If accessing neighboring elements `p[-2], ..., p[5]` is save, one could also load that vector instead of a broadcast and do an in-lane shuffle.

Comment: I really hope I have more knowledge of compilers and choosing compilers, it's like a black box to me so I'd rather not put compiler factors into consideration at this stage

Comment: @Noob: Yeah, I'd recommend writing optimal intrinsics once you've taken the time to figure out what that would look like, if you want your code to compile nicely with multiple compilers.  (e.g. by looking at clang output from `_mm256_setr_ps` and turning that back into intrinsics.)  But using a good compiler like clang means you can get good results with a lot less work, and the compiler will often find better ways to do things when/if you don't think of the best way yourself.  The main point of this answer is the first code block, using `_mm256_broadcast_ps` and `_mm256_permutevar_ps`

Comment: @chtz I see, load seem to have smaller latency than broadcast. Or load anything that contains A,B,C,D eg p[0]~p[7], as long as no memory access violation happens.

Comment: @Noob loading `p[0..7]`  has no advantage over loading `p[0..3]` (as generated by clang for the `duplicate4floats_naive` variant) since both require lane-crossing permutations. Loading `p[-2..5]` is advantageous over a broadcast on some CPUs where broadcasting has higher latency or requires a shuffle µ-op, since you only need one in-lane shuffle afterwards.

Comment: @Noob: Which CPU are you looking at?  Intel's own intrinsics guide shows `vbroadcastf128`  having 7 cycle latency, vs. 6 cycles for `movups` loads.  (With some nonsense numbers like 1c latency on CPUs older than Skylake; Intel's intriniscs finder has mistakes).  But `vpermps` has 3 cycle latency vs. 1 for `vpermilps`.  So broadcast-load + in-lane shuffle wins overall, at 7+1 vs. 6+3 cycles of load-use latency from address to data on Skylake, if Intel's numbers are even correct.  (Although https://uops.info/ does seem to confirm that vbroadcastf128 has 1 cycle higher latency than vmovups.)

Comment: @chtz and Noob: But see also https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=872&v=f#854 - a 128-bit zero-extending load being consumed by a 256-bit vector operation also has extra latency.  So it's probably actually 7+1 vs. 7+3 cycles.  And a 256-bit `vmovups ymm, [mem]` load is 7 cycles.  (Or worse on cache-line split, so on CPUs with cheap `vbroadcastf128` it's best to just do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's a Ryzen 9 3900 XT. I'm targeting CPUs coming out no later than this one.

Answer (score 1):

_mm_load_ps -> _mm256_castps128_ps256 -> _mm256_permute_ps

Comment: `_mm256_permute_ps` is the intrinsic for `vpermilps` because Intel was short-sighted in naming their intrinsics, using "permute" for that AVX1 instruction, and then having to use `_mm256_permutexvar_ps` aka `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` for `vpermps` once AVX2 came along.  But yes, this is most efficient way if you have AVX2, especially if you can load the shuffle control vector only one.

Comment: Otherwise with AVX1, I guess `VBROADCASTF128` / `_mm_permutevar_ps` (vpermilps ymm, ymm, ymm with a vector control).  Actually yeah, that's better because broadcast-load is just as cheap as regular load, and an in-lane shuffle is lower latency, and faster on Zen 1.

Comment: I still don't understand how permute works after reading Intels docs. But this link below really helps. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874396/Crunching-Numbers-with-AVX-and-AVX

Comment: @Noob: `_mm256_permute_ps` *doesn't* actually work for this; this answer had a valid idea but used the wrong intrinsic for `vpermps`.  `__m256 _mm256_permute_ps (__m256 a, int control);` is the intrinsic for `vpermilps` with an immediate control operand (same shuffle in each 128-bit lane) ( https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps).

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right! _mm256_permutevar_ps should do the job